# Why is there such a big difference in the execution time of the convolution operation with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, convolution

Using the numpy convolution function, I found that convolution kernels of size **10000** or smaller perform much faster convolution time than kernels of size **10001** or larger.
What is the reason for such a large difference in time when the kernel increases by only 1.

Here test code:

```
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter as pfc

data = np.random.normal(size=50000)
kernel_low = np.random.normal(size=10000)
kernel_high = np.random.normal(size=10001)

t_start = pfc()
np.convolve(data, kernel_low, 'full')
t_stop = pfc()
print('numpy convolution with kernel = 10000, time=', t_stop - t_start)

t_start = pfc()
np.convolve(data, kernel_high, 'full')
t_stop = pfc()
print('numpy convolution with kernel = 10001, time=', t_stop - t_start)
```

The output:

```
numpy convolution with kernel = 10000, time= 0.0615867999731563
numpy convolution with kernel = 10001, time= 1.6918594000162557
```

Enviroment:
python version 3.11.3
numpy version 1.26.2 and try old version (1.24.3)
windows 10 Pro (version 21H2 build OS 19044.3086)

Any ideas?

Comment: `kernel_high` is 1ms faster for me on M1 Pro numpy 1.25.2 - both around 230ms

Comment: You certainly reached a threshold in the implementation. I can reproduce the issue on Python 3.9.6 on Windows. 0.092s vs 4.82s. My current wild guess is that this could be due to the system allocator.

Comment: Anyway, for large kernels, Numpy is known to be inefficient (`O(n m)` algorithm where `n = len(data)` and `m = len(kernel)`). You should use an FFT-based convolution. Scipy provide such an implementation (running in `O(n log n)` where `n = len(data)`). I expect it to be at least 10x faster here (in the first case).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I already use it in my projects scipy convolution (fft baset) it's much faster for large kernels